# too many column names were specified

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

how can i deal with that error?

```
ERROR:  too many column names were specified
```

i can't figure out what i have to change to make this work.
Is there really too many columns in my CREATE statement or is this in the AS SELECT that goes wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE planification_finale_asset2_test
(   nom,
nom_court,
serveur,
scheduled_backup,
schedule,
retention,
groupe,
remote_access,
alias,
parallelisme,
storage_nodes,
client_OS_type,
version_networker,
savesets,
ALIAS_1,
ALIAS_2,
APPLICATION,
ENVIRONNEMENT,
environnement_global,
IMPACT,
CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL,
TYPE,
SITE,
COMPOSANT_DE,
COMPOSE_DE ,
ETAT,
POIDS,
EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION,
debut_sauvegarde,
groupe_actif,
intervalle,
clones,
retention_policy,
calendrier,
commentaire,
volume_sauvegarde,
volume_externalise,
volume_replique,
"3P2I") AS
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(groupe, ' status ', scheduled_backup) AS etat_groupe,
    CONCAT(groupe, ' status ', groupe_actif) AS etat_groupe_actif,
    t3.volume_sauvegarde, t3.volume_externalise, t3.volume_replique
from planification_client_biens_group_test t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN volumetrie_1_jour t3
    ON t1.nom LIKE CONCAT(t3.client, '%') AND
       t1.serveur = t3.serveur_court;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Either the `CREATE` or `SELECT` has too many columns, as the error message says.  It's tough to say which side is the offender, because you have a `SELECT *` in there, which means take all columns from `t1`, and since we can't see the definition for that table, we probably can't help you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen its about 33 columns (if i counted it well) for t1, all varchar but one in text data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the following query

```
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(groupe, ' status ', scheduled_backup) AS etat_groupe,
    CONCAT(groupe, ' status ', groupe_actif) AS etat_groupe_actif,
    t3.volume_sauvegarde, t3.volume_externalise, t3.volume_replique
into planification_finale_asset2_test from planification_client_biens_group_test t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN volumetrie_1_jour t3
    ON t1.nom LIKE CONCAT(t3.client, '%') AND
       t1.serveur = t3.serveur_court;
```

It will load the data to your table `planification_finale_asset2_test`.

Comment: You want me to create the table and to use your query after? If it's the case i need to specify data type again.

Comment: That was finally the answer that worked for me, i.e. create the table then insert the data. thanks!